# Domain services structuring

Tags: domain-driven-design, services, file-structure, directory-structure

---

Currently i am handling placing my services by their action type like

- App

  - Services

    - Storage
    - Payments

      - Providers
      - Gateways
      - IpnHandler

But i felt like whenever our payment providers are growing i have to check `Gateways / IpnHandler`. And i felt like payment gateway should only care about payment and its result. But i am not quite happy about this structure so that next alternative came in my mind was this

- App

  - Services

    - Storage
    - Payments

      - Paypal

        - Gateway
        - IpnHandler

So how one should structure their folders ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article last Christmas called "[Happy Packaging](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/happy-packaging/)" (suitable for this holiday season also:).

In that I detail 3 simple rules to keep packages organized, to be able to find things, and to keep it maintainable, i.e. to keep changes localized as much as possible:

1. Packages should never depend on sub-packages.
2. Sub-packages should not introduce new concepts, just more details.
3. Packages should reflect business-concepts, not technical ones.

In your case the 3. rule is broken for sure. You organize per technology and that splits up things that belong together logically. So my advice: get rid of all technical concepts in the package structure and focus on the business logic, let the "business" dictate the structure.